# How to pass values from test method to TestNG report

Tags: java, testng

As part of Selenium Automation Framework, I need to write a method to generate custom TestNG report. I know this can be achieved by overriding

```
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory)
```

method in `IReporter` interface. But the problem is that my test methods calculate some values and I have to pass these values to the testNG report. How can I print values from test method in testNG report?

Answer (score 4):

An `ITestResult` object ( this object can be accessed from within a `@Test` method by invoking `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult()` ) basically has a `setAttribute` method which takes in a String key and whose value is an `Object` object.

So you can simply employ something like below within your `@Test` method to save values computed by your test into its corresponding `ITestResult` object and then retrieve it from within your `IReporter` implementation.

```
@Test
public void myTestMethod() {
    Map<String, Object> computedItems = new HashMap<>();
    //Lets assume that the computedItems is what we need to save for retrieval from our reports.
    ITestResult testResult = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    testResult.setAttribute("key", computedItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All test data is stored in ITestResult:

```
for (ISuite suite : suites) {
    ...
    for (ISuiteResult result : suite.getResults().values())
        ...
        IResultMap iFailed = result.getTestContext().getFailedTests();
        for(ITestResult itr: iFailed.getAllResults()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```